# Limit of the $y(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following equation:

> $$ y=(c_1+c_2x)e^{3x} + \frac{10}{b^2}e^{bx} $$

which its solution satisfies $$\lim_{x \to \infty} y(x) =0$$ 
and diverges as $x \to \infty$

Thank you.

Comment: I was going to try and format your equation, but its meaning is ambiguous. Can you please reformat it?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest ,

Mr Avatar has solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $c_1=c_2=0$ and $b\lt 0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}y(x)=0$ and and for $b,c_1,c_2\gt 0, \lim_{x\to\infty}y(x)=\infty$